# Added files not found during execution

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a `MyApp.spec` files where I have:

```
a = Analysis(...
datas=[
       ('file_1.jpg', '.', 
       ('file_2.mplstyle', '.'),
      ]
...)
```

In my code, these files are used in methods as, for example, `plt.style.use('file_2.mplstyle')` (python files and such extra files are in the same folder).

I compile my code with `pyinstaller --onefile MyApp.spec` and it yields no error.

However, at execution time, the `file_2.mplstyle` is not found.

So far, the only trick for the execution to succeed is to manually copy both files to the `dist/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pyplot command assumes the file is in the same directory, where as you, correctly, install it to a separate one.

You need to use the file from where you've installed it!

[Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741) tells you how to find the file in the installed location.